# How can I remove the "apple watch" app, which recently appeared on a home screen?

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-watch

I don't mind that it showed up.
But I want it gone.

[image: Apple watch iOS app application icon]

I could put it into a folder called "things I don't use".
But I'd rather just delete it.

If I ever buy a watch, I can just download the app.

Comment: You can't: http://mashable.com/2015/03/09/apple-watch-app-mandatory/

Comment: I agree that it seems annoying to have these apps that we never use, that we can't get rid of. Spare a thought for the people who WANT an Apple Watch, but can't buy one because it's not available in their country - and yet they still get to see the app on their phone, and can't remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't remove several of the Apple-supplied apps (try removing the ever-useful Stocks app, for example).

The Apple Watch app is one of these.

Generally, people tend to move these to a folder that they use to hide the 'useless' apps, or move them to a different screen - just so you're not staring at them all the time.

Where I live, the Apple Watch is not even available yet, but still I got the app staring at me to remind me of this constantly. It got hidden pretty quickly!